# "Take a quest" or "Take up a quest"?

Tags: grammar, phrasal-verbs

> If I take this quest, I shall be redeemed in her eyes.

*vs*

> Take up the quest to receive a handsome reward!

Which usage is semantically correct or (if both correct) better? `Take` or `take up` or `take on` (thanks, @mplungjan!) or maybe even `take up on`?

Comment: I was surprised when I looked [here](http://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=take+this+quest%2Ctake+up+this+quest%2Ctake+the+quest%2Ctake+up+the+quest&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=0&smoothing=3&share=) But you could have easily taken (up) this particular quest yourself.

Comment: Take _on_ this quest could also work, no?

Answer (score 1):

"Quest" is a search, or the object of the search.

"take up" means here "become interested in a pursuit".

"take up the quest ..." then means correctly something like : "start your investigation".

"take" has many meanings, but I do not feel comfortable with "take this quest".